# \autocite Highlighted yet works?

Tags: biblatex, texstudio

I have problem in which I am using `\autocite` within TexMakerX and it is being highlighted as an unrecognized command yet, when I use the LaTeX to PDF command, it seems to work.  There is no error when I run LaTeX on the document.

In addition, I would like the citation to include the author's name in the footnote, currently it is just the title, publisher, etc.

My document looks like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\begin{document}

Hello World!\autocite{clare2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: TeXMakerX is a front-end for editing (La)TeX files. As such, what TeXMakerX (or any other editor) highlights as 'known' is not directly linked to what LaTeX itself will recognise.

Comment: Ok, thank a lot for your help.  I am also using Miktext.  Is there a package I could add so that it would "know"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, TexmakerX has changed name to TeXstudio, so if you're running TexmakerX you probably have an old version. I would upgrade.

The commands recognized by TeXstudio are defined in `.cwl` files, and your version doesn't have such a file for `biblatex`. The current stable version doesn't have this either, but the latest build from SVN does. You have three options:

1. Get the [`biblatex.cwl` file from SourceForge](http://texstudio.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/texstudio/trunk/completion/biblatex.cwl?view=log) and place it in the correct folder, as described in section 1.4 of the TeXstudio manual. The folder is found in the AppData folder in your user folder, e.g. `c:\Documents and Settings\User\AppData\Roaming\texstudio`.

   (A tip: In Windows 7, and at least some older versions of Windows, `%appdata%` is a kind of shortcut to get to the AppData (or AppData/Roaming). Just type `%appdata%` in the address bar in Explorer or the search bar on the start menu, and hit enter.)
2. Install the latest SVN-version of TeXstudio: [direct link to download on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/texstudio/files/texstudio/TeXstudio%20SVN/texstudio23_svn2778_win32.exe/download). As this isn't really released yet, I suppose there may be bugs that aren't fixed.
3. Wait for the next stable version (2.4).

Comment: Success! Thank you very much.  It was very clear what to do with your help in addition to the user's manual.